# Patch module entry and exit - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, mocking, monkeypatching

I have a module called my_module whose performance I want to measure.

`my_module` has multiple functions and what I want to do is, whenever any function from the module is called

- Note down the entry time
- Note down the exit time

So let's say I ran this - `my_module.func('blah')`

I wish to print

- Function call started at 100001201
- Function call ended at 100001312

for any function in the module.

I cannot make any direct changes to the module file as it has to be used in other places as well. I just need this to print for the performance test script.

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it on Numpy module, so you should be able to use the same method for for any module:

```
import numpy as np                           # import the module you want to be logged
from inspect import getmembers, isfunction   # These will give us the functions in a module
import time                                  # for logging the time

class Object(object):                        # make a dummy class on which we can do "setattr()"
    pass

numpy_with_time_logger = Object()            # We are going to make numpy_with_time_logger work exactly like Numpy except that it will also print start and end times


def return_call_time_logger(f):              # This function takes in a function and returns a new function!
    def call_time_logger(*args, **kargs):    # This function is going to substitute f. It runs f(), but it also prints the times.
        print(f'Function call started at {time.time()}')
        ret_val = f(*args, **kargs)
        print(f'Function call ended at {time.time()}')
        return ret_val
    return call_time_logger

for f_name, f in getmembers(numpy, isfunction): # For every function inside numpy module
    # Set numpy_with_time_logger.f_name to be return_call_time_logger(f)
    setattr(numpy_with_time_logger, f_name, return_call_time_logger(f))
```

Note: To make it work for your own module, just change the "numpy" in `getmembers(numpy, isfunction)` to the name of your imported module.

Now, our numpy_with_time_logger object is set to work exactly like Numpy, but it will also print the start and end times. So try using any of numpy's functions through numpy_with_time_logger:

```
print(numpy_with_time_logger.asarray([1,2]))
```

The output is:

```
start time 1615096471.112301
end time 1615096471.1134446
array([1, 2])
```

#### An issue with this method:

If you call `numpy_with_time_logger.func1()` and `numpy_with_time_logger.func1()` calls `numpy.func2()`, then you will only get the time logs for `func1`, and you won't get the time logs for `func2`.

To access the global variables defined in Numpy module, just keep using `numpy`, e.g. `numpy.int32` .